# Cordova plugin: Delay deviceready event

Tags: android, events, cordova, delay, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to delay the `deviceready` event in a custom plugin? If yes how?

In particular I have to wait for a callback in my native android code. The `deviceready` is currently triggered **before** the callback and thus provides access to a not-ready plugin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not if this is the correct solution. Call another function after delay in deviceReady().

Comment: Could you please be a more precise?

Comment: function onDeviceReady() {
    setTimeout(yourFunction, 3000);
}
now yourFunction will be called after 3 seconds delay.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you can successfully call javascript function after your native callback fires, that means after the callback function fires you can call a javascript method, if so then in that javascript method
initialize the deviceready.

```
function callback_js()
{

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

}
```

Then the deviceready listner will only be initialized after this method is called.

If you can't call the js code after native execution,then I think you'll need custom plugin to interact with both js and native code.